# The constructor is deprecated

Tags: android

I make one android application.In my code in my java class I get some message: "The constructor Notification(int, CharSequence, long) is deprecated". Everything is ok with Application I don't have problem when I try to run the Application. 
 I just want to know why this message is showing up.
My code in my java class is:

```
public class Notifications extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.notifications);

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bNotifications);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                Notification notify = new Notification(
                        android.R.drawable.stat_notify_more,
                        "This is important", System.currentTimeMillis());
                Context context = Notifications.this;
                CharSequence title = "You have been notified";
                CharSequence details = "Continue with what you have doing";
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                        intent, 0);
                notify.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, details, pending);
                nm.notify(0, notify);

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have a look at [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#Notification%28int,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20long%29):

> public **Notification** (int icon, CharSequence tickerText, long when) 
>   Added in API level 1
>
> **This constructor was deprecated in API level 11.**
>   Use [Notification.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html) instead.

As far as I can tell, this would be the corresponding call to `Notification.Builder`:

```
Context context = Notifications.this;
Notification notify = new Notification.Builder(context)
     .setTicker("This is important")
     .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_more)
     .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
     .build();
```

As you can see, Notification.Builder offers more flexibility in setting the various notification properties and improves code readability, which might be the reason why the Notification constructor was deprecated.

Comment: I would like to use this code in a project which should be compatible upto API level 8. But I cant see any extensions to use it since its not in v4 package

Comment: @Heinzi I can't find Notifications class to create context. There is only Notification class without 's' but context object won't accept it.

Comment: @MinNaingOo: Replace `Notifications` with the class name of your activity. (See the first line in the code example of the original question.)

Comment: @Heinzi So this is same with passing 'this' as parameter context? `new Notification.Builder(this)`

Comment: @MinNaingOo: Yes, sure, unless you are inside an inner class definition (note the `new View.OnClickListener() { ... }` in the original question).

Comment: APIs under 11 need `NotificationCompat.Builder`

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the fact that a method is deprecated doesn't mean that you won't need it nor make use of it. So, after all, you need to support older devices (not the oldest like Android Donut or previous) and you will need to use the new way and the deprecated way. In this case, I've implemented as follows:

```
Notification notification;
String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
   notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
}else{
   notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
   .setContentTitle(title)
   .setContentText(message)
   .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
   .build();
}
```

Hope that it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Since API level 11 `Notification(int icon, CharSequence tickerText, long when)` is no longer advised to be used as there exists an alternative to this. Use Notification.Builder instead.

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#Notification(int, java.lang.CharSequence, long)