# Changing Notifications on android code to use notification.builder

Tags: java, android, notifications

I am not a developer, and am trying to get some sample code working nicely. 
The API I am running against, is not 100% compatible with my code I am using.(API15).

Would anyone be able to help me reformat this code to work with the newer style [builder notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20329506/the-constructor-is-deprecated)?

(I had a try, but cant work out the right way of doing it based on the question linked)

```
{           
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Robot service running", System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Robot Service", "Click to stop", PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, new Intent("stop", null, this, this.getClass()), 0));
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    nm.notify(0, notification);     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(mContext)
         .setContentTitle("New mail from " + sender.toString())
         .setContentText(subject)
         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_mail)
         .setLargeIcon(aBitmap)
         .build();
```

For more detail use below link:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html